# loading a dictionary of files as if it were 1 file, in requireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, manifest, require

I`m trying to write a game engine in javascript, what i would like to do is load all the engine code before the game code can be executed. Now, that's only the first step, because what i would also like to do is load all the engine code inside the game code in one file. So I would have a boot file where I load all my engine code, return the main game object and return that inside the game code.

```
define(['engine'[,...[]]], function(engine){
    // do what you want in order for you to make a game
});
```

In my engine file I would load all the engine code, something like:

```
requirejs.config({
        baseUrl: '/js/libraries/engine',
        paths: {

            message         : "message",
            debug           : "debug",
            vector2         : "helpers/vector2",
            settings        : "settings",
            engine          : "engine",
            loop            : "loop",
            extra           : "extras",
            scene           : "scene",
            scenemanager    : "scenemanager",
            audio           : "audio",
            input           : "input",
            canvas          : "canvas",
            drawable        : "drawables/drawable",
            sprite          : "drawables/sprite",
            animation       : "drawables/animation",
            boxcollider     : "colliders/boxcollider",
            spherecollider  : "colliders/spherecollider",
            actor           : "actor",
            world           : "world"

        }
});

require(["message", "debug", "vector2", "settings", "engine", "loop", "extra", "scene", "scenemanager",
            "audio", "input","canvas","drawable","sprite","animation","boxcollider", "spherecollider", "actor", "world"]
    , function(
            message,   debug,    vector2,   settings,   engine,   loop,   extra,   scene,  scenemanager,
            audio,   input,   canvas, drawable, sprite,   animation,   boxcollider,   spherecollider,   actor,  world)
        {
         return engine;
        }
    );
```

So basically, the engine.js file would become a manifest for the engine code, and I only want to load the engine.js file to have access to all the components defined in there. I just don't see how to do it currently.

Answer (score 0):

To create a single (possibly minified) file, use the [RequireJS optimiser](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html).

In terms of the layout of the files:

### engine.js

engine is defined in here, and has dependencies on all the rest of the engine sub-components.

```
define(["message", "debug", "vector2", "settings", "loop", "extra", "scene", "scenemanager",
        "audio", "input","canvas","drawable","sprite","animation","boxcollider", "spherecollider", "actor", "world"]
, function(
        message,   debug,    vector2,   settings,   loop,   extra,   scene,   scenemanager,
        audio,   input,   canvas, drawable, sprite,   animation,   boxcollider,   spherecollider,   actor,  world) {
        var engine = ...;
        return engine;
    }
);
```

### index.html

```
<head>
...
<script>
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/js/libraries/',
    paths: {
        engine          : "engine",
        message         : "message",
        debug           : "debug",
        vector2         : "helpers/vector2",
        settings        : "settings",
        engine          : "engine",
        loop            : "loop",
        extra           : "extras",
        scene           : "scene",
        scenemanager    : "scenemanager",
        audio           : "audio",
        input           : "input",
        canvas          : "canvas",
        drawable        : "drawables/drawable",
        sprite          : "drawables/sprite",
        animation       : "drawables/animation",
        boxcollider     : "colliders/boxcollider",
        spherecollider  : "colliders/spherecollider",
        actor           : "actor",
        world           : "world"
    }
});
</script>
<script>
require(['engine'], function(engine) {
    // do something with the game
});
</script>
...
</head>
```